# Is it possible to see the converted leads on Lead object without coding?

Tags: apex, soap-api, leads, list-view, view

After converting the lead am i able to see the lead on Lead object without any hard coding?.

Comment: Are you talking about anywhere or at a specific place?

Answer (score 2):

Once you've converted them, the leads are no longer available in a list view directly on the Leads tab. The easiest way I've come across to view them is by creating a report using the "Leads With Converted Lead Information" report type. Hope that helps!